# Enabling left navigation for communication SharePoint site

Tags: quick-launch, communication-site

I created a communication site using blank template. How do i enable left  navigation(quick launch)? top menu is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Microsoft is of the opinion that a Communication Site should not have any left nav as per https://www.wortell.nl/blogs/modern-sharepoint-sites-navigation-options/ and similar sources